# Which data directories are needed to do backup copies for Apache IoTDB Version 0.13?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does the data file of the Apache IoTDB stand-alone Version 0.13 support the processing of backup copies when the database is running online? If I want to set up backup data copies, which data directory files need to be copied?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the data files to do backup when Apache IoTDB is still running, but when copying, you need to pay attention to also copy the corresponding resource file of every tsfile, so that the tsfile is complete. You can copy the files in `data/system`, `data/data`, `data/wal` directories.